# NSUserActivity Not Getting Indexed by Spotlight

Tags: ios, ios9, spotlight, nsuseractivity, ios-searchapi

I'm trying to get my NSUserActivity to be indexed by the private index in Spotlight in iOS. I have followed all the steps in [Apple's Index Activities and Navigation Points](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/Activities.html) guide but my activity doesn't seem to be getting indexed by spotlight at all.

The guide says that:

> To guarantee that the activity and its metadata get indexed, you must
>   hold a strong reference to the activity until it gets added to the
>   index. There are two ways to do this: The first way is to assign the
>   activity to a property in the controller object that creates the
>   activity. The second way is to use the userActivity property of the
>   UIResponder object.

I opted to do the first option (to create a a property in my view controller to hold the NSUserActivity).

```
var lastSearchedUserActivity: NSUserActivity?
```

The idea is that, when the user searches for something, his last query is indexed on the device. I have the following method that prepares the user activity and (supposedly) indexes it:

```
func prepareLastSearchedUserActivity(tags: [String], server: Server) {
    if Settings.applicationIndexedUserActivitiesAsShortcutTypes.contains(.LastSearched) {
        print("Get ready to index. and tags \(tags.reduce("") { "\($0) \($1)" })")
        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: ShortcutType.LastSearched.rawValue)

        activity.title = server.serverName
        activity.userInfo = ["tags": tags, "server name": server.serverName]

        let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet()
        attributeSet.contentDescription = tags.reduce("") { "\($0) \($1)" }
        attributeSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = ShortcutType.LastSearched.rawValue

        activity.contentAttributeSet = attributeSet
        activity.keywords = Set(tags)
        activity.eligibleForSearch = true
        activity.eligibleForHandoff = false
        activity.becomeCurrent()
        self.lastSearchedUserActivity = activity
        //self.lastSearchedUserActivity?.becomeCurrent()
    }
}
```

This method gets called without an issue, but the activity is not searchable: I have tried to search in Spotlight using the `title` assigned to it, and the `keywords`. The activity never shows up.

I have tried many solutions, including:

- To move the `eligibleForSearch` call directly after creating the activity. Apple's guide doesn't say anything about this directly, but the code snippets in the provided link seem to imply that setting this line to `true` should add the activity to the index automatically.
- Apple doesn't say that `becomeCurrent()` should be called, but rather that it will be called for you (how? No idea). Regardless like you can see, I tried calling it myself. I also tried calling it after assigning it to my property. No dice. Apple does say that when calling `becomeCurrent()` on an activity that has `eligibleForSearch` as `true`, it will be added to the index.
- I even went as far as using the view controller's `userActivity` property directly for the creation and configuration of the activity. Because I'm using the provided property, it shouldn't be deallocating early.

As far as I can tell, I am doing everything Apple does in their guide. I am completely lost.

I am testing on an iPhone 6S+ so Spotlight indexing is available. The console does not print anything related to Spotlight, either.

### Update:

I just set the delegate of the activity to `self` and implemented the `userActivityWillSave` method.

According to the [`NSUserActivityDelegate` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSUserActivityDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSUserActivityDelegate/userActivityWillSave:), about `userActivityWillSave:`

> Notifies the delegate that the user activity will be saved to be
>   continued or persisted.

So this delegate method is getting called, but the indexed item is nowhere to be found. Here's the updated code:

```
func prepareLastSearchedUserActivity(tags: [String], server: Server) {
    if Settings.applicationIndexedUserActivitiesAsShortcutTypes.contains(.LastSearched) {
        print("Get ready to index. and tags \(tags.reduce("") { "\($0) \($1)" })")
        let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: ShortcutType.LastSearched.rawValue)

        activity.title = server.serverName
        activity.userInfo = ["tags": tags, "server name": server.serverName]
        activity.delegate = self

        let attributeSet = CSSearchableItemAttributeSet()
        attributeSet.contentDescription = tags.reduce("") { "\($0) \($1)" }
        attributeSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = ShortcutType.LastSearched.rawValue

        activity.contentAttributeSet = attributeSet
        activity.keywords = Set(tags)
        activity.eligibleForSearch = true
        activity.eligibleForHandoff = false
        self.lastSearchedUserActivity = activity
        activity.becomeCurrent()
        //self.lastSearchedUserActivity?.becomeCurrent()
    }
}

func userActivityWillSave(userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    print("Yep it will save")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out setting the `relatedUniqueIdentifier` in the attribute set causes the `userInfo` dictionary to be discarded.

I commented this line out:

```
attributeSet.relatedUniqueIdentifier = ShortcutType.LastSearched.rawValue
```

And it is now working as expected. Though I will need to find another way to delete my user activities from the index.

### Update: More Information

If you must use a unique identifier, for your activity, then you need to index it with Core Spotlight first, and then index the `NSUserActivity` itself. If you try to use the `relatedUniqueIdentifier` without using it in Spotlight first, the `NSUserActivity` will not be indexed. This was the problem in my case.

From the [`relatedUniqueIdentifier` property documentation in the `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CSSearchableItemAttributeSet/relatedUniqueIdentifier):

> If you’re using both NSUserActivity and Core Spotlight APIs to index
>   the same item, set this property in the activity to specify the unique
>   identifier of the Core Spotlight item to which the activity is
>   related, and to avoid displaying duplicate results in Spotlight.
>
> If the unique identifier to which the activity is related hasn’t
>   already been indexed with Core Spotlight, the activity won’t be
>   indexed.

Comment: This worked for me too but now I am not sure if the `NSUserActivity` is being publicly indexed or not when keeping the `relatedUniqueIdentifier` so they match with the Core Spotlight items. Does anyone know or is there a way to search the public index?